# Access Denied using Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate

Tags: powershell, azure-keyvault

I have a seemingly simple script for importing a PFX into Azure Key Vault. The service principal I am using is set to the Key Vault contributor role and has the access policies Get, List, Update, Create and Import. I am using certificate authentication when connecting the service principal. However, I get a very unhelpful error:

```
 Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate : Access denied.
 At line:1 char:1
 + Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $keyVault -Name 'AzureAuth' - ...
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate], CryptographicException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.ImportAzureKeyVaultCertificate
```

My Script:

```
 $PFX = "$env:TEMP\cert-lab.pfx"
    
 $tenantID = 'xxx'
 $AppID = 'xxx'
 $keyVault = 'LabKV'
 $assetName = 'AzureCert'
 $EncryptPass = 'PFXpassword123'
    
 ## Clear the authentication context
 Clear-AzContext -Force
    
 $PFXPass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $EncryptPass -AsPlainText -Force
 $pfxCert = Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $PFX -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -Password $PFXPass -Exportable
    
 $ctx = Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $tenantID -CertificateThumbprint $pfxCert.Thumbprint -ApplicationId $AppID
    
 Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $keyVault -Name $assetName -FilePath $PFX -Password $PFXPass -DefaultProfile $ctx
```

Interestingly, if I manually import the cert through the console, I can use the exact same code with Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate instead of Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate and successfully retrieve the certificate. This tells me that the Service Principal at least has access to retrieve certificates. I'm still at a loss as to what is causing the Import to fail.

Comment: Could you share what access policies you assigned to the service principal?

Comment: From your code, you uploaded the .pfx certificate for your AD App then use it to login? And you want to import the same certificate to keyvault? As I know, .pfx certificate is not supported for AD App, how did you do that?

Comment: @JoyWang - Correct.  The App only needs the public key so will not take a PFX.  I just send it the PEM.  However, I need to validate the installation by somehow retrieving the certificate.  One can only do that with the KeyVault.  As far as I know it is not possible to retrieve anything but the thumbprint once the cert is installed on the app.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up buying a support plan and opening a case with Microsoft.  Even though I was able to directly import cert-lab.pfx and was able to verify its contents with OpenSSL, for whatever reason, Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate just did not like the file.  They had me create a new file by exporting from my CAPI store to cert2.pfx.  The import command worked flawlessly with the new file.  I shrugged my shoulders, deleted the old file and decided to move on with my life.

Comment: I couldn't let it lie.  The real answer is that Azure must have the certificate chain included in the PFX.  The utility I was using to export the file was not including its issuer.  Azure hated that.